# NSParagraphStyle line spacing ignored

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, ios6, nsattributedstring

A simple test that is failed:  Make a new project with just one subview (UITextView) and put the following in:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 50.f;
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 100.f;
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 200.f;
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 500.f;

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:24.f];

    self.textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:
    @"This is a test.\n Will I pass?" attributes:
    @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle, NSFontAttributeName : font}];
}
```

Line spacing is the same as if the attribute were not there.  Has anything got this to work successfully?  I put in ridiculous numbers just to show that it won't change...

Comment: I'm having the same issue..have you figured out a solution?

Comment: @mohabitar The solution appears to be wait until Apple fixes it.  An alternative would be to use DTCoreText and implement your own selection.  Most of the selection code is available in an Apple sample called SimpleTextInput (it is disabled by default, but it is there).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a bug in NSHTMLWriter which is the private class which UITextView uses to convert attributedText into HTML. Internally it displays this HTML via a UIWebDocumentView. Read more on the inner workings of UITextView in my writeup here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/12/uitextview-caught-with-trousers-down/

The problem comes from an easy to miss speciality in the font CSS shorthand. If you specify a pixel size with the font shorthand then this sets BOTH the font-size as well as the line-height. Since NSHTMLWriter puts the font AFTER the line-height this causes the line-height to be cancelled out by the font size.

See here for my Radar which includes the full analysis of the bug: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/12/radar-uitextview-ignores-minimummaximum-line-height-in-attributed-string/

I suggest you file a bug report as well and mention my Radar #12863734.

Comment: I would love to, but actually I have never been able to log into the bug report website...I emailed to complain but never got a response :-S. This is interesting though!

Comment: You should telephone DTS, they can help you there. Phone number depending on your country on the website.

Comment: Please consider posting follow up if Apple ever responds. Thanks for this!

Comment: @Cocoanetics In iOS 7, I'm having a similar, possibly related problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232006/uilabel-applying-line-break-mode-to-only-a-portion-of-the-text

Answer (score 23):

I don't know if this is enough for your purposes but I could adjust the line spacing by setting the minimum and maximum line height. Furthermore to use a font I put it into the `font` property of the text view rather than passing it as the value of `NSFontAttributeName` in the attributes dictionary. (Maybe this part is not (well) documented?)

#### About your attributes

`lineSpacing` is calculated from the bottom of the line to the bottom of the upper line and that space is constrained to values between `minimumLineHeight` and `miximumLineHeight`. What I am trying to say is that maybe some values in your attributes are *cancelling* or *overriding* others.

Also if you need to just adjust the spacing between line you probably don't need to use `paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple` :)

#### The code

This worked for me:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 35.f;
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 35.f;

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:18.f];
NSString *string = @"This is a test.\nWill I pass?\n日本語のもじもあるEnglish\nEnglish y Español";
NSDictionary *attributtes = @{
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
};
self.textView.font = font;
self.textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string
                                 attributes:attributtes];
```

[image]

#### Additional Notes

There seems to be a situation with Japanese/Chinesse and maybe other characters mixed with alphabet characters in the same line. It will make that line to have a bigger *leading* to solve that you need to set up the minimum and maximum line height as I did.
You can see the problem when rendering my example without attributes.

Comment: This might be enough.  I'll look into it when I go back to the office.

Comment: Thought I should comment that this won't work since I will mix fonts in the same label :-S (Italic, regular, etc).

Comment: This approach should work as long as you use the same font size. Italics and regulars will result in the same line height.

Comment: When I set the font via NSFontAttributeName, the line spacing starts to be ignored again..that's the big problem (there is no other way to mix styles in the same label).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298748/using-attributedtext-nsattributedstring-on-a-uitextview-on-ios6-only-works-wit?rq=1

Comment: @borrrden - did you ever find a solution for this I'm wondering?

Answer (score 9):

Setting maximumLineHeight seems to resolve this issue for me;

```
CGFloat fontSize = 22.f;
titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[[NSMutableParagraphStyle  alloc] init] autorelease];
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = fontSize/2;
titleLabel.attributedText = [[[NSAttributedString alloc]
                              initWithString:@"This is a test.\nWill I pass?"
                              attributes: @{ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                                             NSFontAttributeName : titleLabel.font}]
                             autorelease];
```

[image: overlapping lines]

Answer (score 5):

For this particular string you need to set `paragraphSpacing` instead. What's about `lineSpacing`, I believe it's just not supported yet on iOS.

Comment: Good tip about paragraph spacing +1.  However, I am looking to stop using UIWebView...so until UITextView can do CSS line-height I can't...

Answer (score 0):

As nacho4d answered, in **iOS 6** you need to use **minimumLineHeight** and **maximumLineHeight** and set font directly in **UITextView**, not in **NSAttributedString** as line height in that case will be overridden.

Please note that when you set font in **UITextView**, the **"editable"** property of **UITextView** should be set to **YES**, in other case **attributed text** would not be affected.

These issues are present only in **iOS 6**. In **iOS 7** and above everything is ok;

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the paragraph styling was working. The fix was to set the attributed text on the label AFTER doing any frame adjustments on the label. :)