# Can't calculate the height of the attributed string

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I try to solve the issue with the `NSAttributedString` and the html in it. I try to draw it in the `UILabel` as the attributed text in the `UITableViewCell`.

I have a html string:

```
<span class=\"\">Безвозмездно</span>
```

So I made an attributed string with the method:

```
+ (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringWithHTML:(NSString *)HTML {
    NSDictionary *options = @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType };
    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[HTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:options documentAttributes:NULL error:NULL];
}
```

and then I try to calculate the string height in the class method to get the cell height. I use:

```
if (attrString.length > 0) {
    height += truncf([attrString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                              context:nil].size.height) + 1.0f;
}
```

So I get the height of the label that is smaller than the label which I get with:

```
[self.titleLabel sizeToFit];
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that you need to specify the font and its size to get the correct size for the bounding rect?

Comment: All I have the html string like in post above - how can I change the font and its size?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694137/setting-font-on-nsattributedstring-on-uitextview-disregards-line-spacing

Answer (score 0):

I have met this question as well as. And at present I find it appears in UILabel and UITextView. In my opinion it's a bug of Apple. Thus, in order to guarantee the accuracy of result, I prefer to get the height with : `[self.titleLabel sizeToFit]`