# NSAttributedString, change the font overall BUT keep all other attributes?

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

Say I have an `NSMutableAttributedString` .

The string has **a varied *mix*** of formatting throughout:

Here is an example:

> This string is **hell to *change*** *in iOS*, it *really* **sucks**.

However, the font per se is not the font you want.

I want to:

**for each and every character, change that character to a specific *font* (say, Avenir)**

## BUT,

**for each and every character, *keep* the *mix* of *other* attributions (bold, italic, colors, etc etc) which was previously in place on that character.**

How the hell do you do this?

---

Note:

if you trivially add an attribute "Avenir" over the whole range: it simply **deletes all the other attribute ranges**, you lose all formatting. Unfortunately, attributes **are not**, in fact "additive".

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1409691-removeattribute to remove the `NSFontAttributeName`. You can also use https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1412461-enumerateattribute to enumerate and decide if the font is to be removed or not.

Comment: Why don't you simply get the string from your attributedString and create a new attributedString with the desired font http://stackoverflow.com/a/28132610/2303865

Comment: You said remove all attributes

Comment: I see you changed your question, then unupvoted & downvoted my answer to your original question and finished up by writing your own answer and accepting it as the solution. Poor show.

Comment: Man, no offense, but your formatting sucks. You should remove some font attributes - pun intended.

Comment: @Fattie, how does manmal's post not answer your question? I had *exactly* your problem and his solution works really well.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Since rmaddy's answer did not work for me (`f.fontDescriptor.withFace(font.fontName)` does not keep traits like bold), here is an updated Swift 4 version that also includes color updating:

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func setFontFace(font: UIFont, color: UIColor? = nil) {
        beginEditing()
        self.enumerateAttribute(
            .font, 
            in: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length)
        ) { (value, range, stop) in

            if let f = value as? UIFont, 
              let newFontDescriptor = f.fontDescriptor
                .withFamily(font.familyName)
                .withSymbolicTraits(f.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits) {

                let newFont = UIFont(
                    descriptor: newFontDescriptor, 
                    size: font.pointSize
                )
                removeAttribute(.font, range: range)
                addAttribute(.font, value: newFont, range: range)
                if let color = color {
                    removeAttribute(
                        .foregroundColor, 
                        range: range
                    )
                    addAttribute(
                        .foregroundColor, 
                        value: color, 
                        range: range
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        endEditing()
    }
}
```

**Or,** if your mix-of-attributes does not include font,
then you don't need to remove old font:

```swift
let myFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize);

myAttributedText.addAttributes(
    [NSAttributedString.Key.font: myFont],
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: myAttributedText.string.count));
```

---

### Notes

The problem with `f.fontDescriptor.withFace(font.fontName)` is that it removes symbolic traits like `italic`, `bold` or `compressed`, since it will for some reason override those with default traits of that font face. Why this is so totally eludes me, it might even be an oversight on Apple's part; or it's "not a bug, but a feature", because we get the new font's traits for free.

So what we have to do is create a font descriptor that has the symbolic traits from the original font's font descriptor: `.withSymbolicTraits(f.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits)`. Props to rmaddy for the initial code on which I iterated.

I've already shipped this in a production app where we parse a HTML string via `NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html` and then change the font and color via the extension above. No problems so far.

Comment: It's `f.fontDescriptor.withFamily(font.familyName).withSymbolicTraits(f.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits)` that was different in rmaddy's code. Compare the code in his edit history.

Comment: @Fattie Oh I was silently logged out for a time and totally missed your comments, sorry! Thanks for the bounty :) In the meantime, I've released the above snippet as part of a production app, so yes it does indeed work. I'll try and elaborate a bit in the post above.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Thanks for removing method chaining, I agree that it's not of much use here.

Comment: understood @manmal thanks again.  yes what a nightmare!  in some apps you have to do things that iOS really "doesn't want to do" and this is an example of that.

Comment: I discovered a minor bug in this implementation. If any part of the string has NO font attribute, then it won't be replaced. So you need to add `} else { addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: range) }` after the inner `if` block. Same for color if you need that.

Comment: Thanks @manmal. I'm having a hard time trying to get the bold text to work. Your code just ignores the bold parts of the html. Any idea how i can achieve this?

Comment: @ShyamBhat the code should actually work for bold text. my idea is that perhaps the text in your html is not made bold with `<b></b>` tags, but with CSS? That would perhaps work with inline CSS (haven't tried this yet), but not with an external CSS file.

Comment: @manmal nope the code snippet doesn't work with <b></b> attributes, do you have an idea to fix this problem ?

Comment: @JAHelia sorry i can't check right now - have you tried with inline CSS like `style="font-weight: bold"`?

Comment: There's also the possibility that the font you are using does not have a bold trait. I noticed that even the system fonts react differently depending on iOS version.

Comment: @manmal I've tried font-weight:bold but didn't actually worked, but I guess it something relates to the font itself, the font may not have a bold weight

Comment: @JAHelia if you are using a font that is shipped with ios, you can check here whether there is bold available: http://iosfonts.com

Comment: Why is the `if let color = color` nested inside the `if let f = value as? UIFont`, when they are modifying different attributes (i.e. `.font` vs. `.foregroundColor`)? Seems more appropriate to hike the color mod outside the `enumerateAttribute()` call so it is always executed.

Comment: @AndrewKirna The color mod needs `range` as parameter, so it cannot be put outside `enumerateAttribute()`. I also put it inside the other `if let` because I don't want to change the color if the font is not changed. That's a personal preference of course.

Comment: @manmal, yes, it's personal preference. I'm applying a static color to the full range. It's working for me with `let fullStringRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: length)`, `removeAttribute(.foregroundColor, range: fullStringRange)`, and `addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: color, range: fullStringRange)` in a `NSMutableAttributedString` extension.

Comment: Works with dynamic type fonts as well.  Nice!

Answer (score 11):

Here is a much simpler implementation that keeps all attributes in place, including all font attributes except it allows you to change the font face.

Note that this only makes use of the font face (name) of the passed in font. The size is kept from the existing font. If you want to also change all of the existing font sizes to the new size, change `f.pointSize` to `font.pointSize`.

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func replaceFont(with font: UIFont) {
        beginEditing()
        self.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length)) { (value, range, stop) in
            if let f = value as? UIFont {
                let ufd = f.fontDescriptor.withFamily(font.familyName).withSymbolicTraits(f.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits)!
                let newFont = UIFont(descriptor: ufd, size: f.pointSize)
                removeAttribute(.font, range: range)
                addAttribute(.font, value: newFont, range: range)
            }
        }
        endEditing()
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
let someMutableAttributedString = ... // some attributed string with some font face you want to change
someMutableAttributedString.replaceFont(with: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12))
```

Comment: Dude I fear this may not actually work.  As someone else also reports below there is a problem w/ bold.  It takes an incredibly long time to fully test this stuff, and, unfortunately, me and my merry men have not yet had a chance to fully investigate it, but some quick tests seemed to fail.  :O  There are so many factors involved it is a real nightmare; it could be our test was messed up.  :O

Comment: I really could have sworn that I tested this with a bold font but sure enough it wasn't working in a playground with Xcode 9.2. I've update the creating of the font descriptor and it's now working as expected.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Yes, manmal fixed my answer (and added support for a color). I've updated my answer by fixing that one line of code so it works in all conditions.

Answer (score 7):

my two cents for OSX/AppKit>

```
extension NSAttributedString {
// replacing font to all:
func setFont(_ font: NSFont, range: NSRange? = nil)-> NSAttributedString {
    let mas = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
    let range = range ?? NSMakeRange(0, self.length)
    mas.addAttributes([.font: font], range: range)
    return NSAttributedString(attributedString: mas)
}


// keeping font, but change size:
func setFont(size: CGFloat, range: NSRange? = nil)-> NSAttributedString {
    let mas = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
    let range = range ?? NSMakeRange(0, self.length)
    
    
    mas.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: range) { value, range, stop in
        if let font = value as? NSFont {
            let name = font.fontName
            let newFont = NSFont(name: name, size: size)
            mas.addAttributes([.font: newFont!], range: range)
        }
    }
    return NSAttributedString(attributedString: mas)
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Obj-C version of @manmal's answer

```
@implementation NSMutableAttributedString (Additions)

- (void)setFontFaceWithFont:(UIFont *)font color:(UIColor *)color {
    [self beginEditing];
    [self enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                     inRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)
                     options:0
                  usingBlock:^(id  _Nullable value, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                      UIFont *oldFont = (UIFont *)value;
                      UIFontDescriptor *newFontDescriptor = [[oldFont.fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFamily:font.familyName] fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:oldFont.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits];
                      UIFont *newFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:newFontDescriptor size:font.pointSize];
                      if (newFont) {
                          [self removeAttribute:NSFontAttributeName range:range];
                          [self addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:newFont range:range];
                      }

                      if (color) {
                          [self removeAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName range:range];
                          [self addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:newFont range:range];
                      }
                  }];
    [self endEditing];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Important -**

rmaddy has invented an entirely new technique for this annoying problem in iOS.

The answer by manmal is the final perfected version.

Purely for **the historical record** here is roughly how you'd go about doing it the old days...

---

```
// carefully convert to "our" font - "re-doing" any other formatting.
// change each section BY HAND.  total PITA.

func fixFontsInAttributedStringForUseInApp() {

    cachedAttributedString?.beginEditing()

    let rangeAll = NSRange(location: 0, length: cachedAttributedString!.length)

    var boldRanges: [NSRange] = []
    var italicRanges: [NSRange] = []

    var boldANDItalicRanges: [NSRange] = [] // WTF right ?!

    cachedAttributedString?.enumerateAttribute(
            NSFontAttributeName,
            in: rangeAll,
            options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired)
                { value, range, stop in

                if let font = value as? UIFont {

                    let bb: Bool = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)
                    let ii: Bool = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitItalic)

                    // you have to carefully handle the "both" case.........

                    if bb && ii {

                        boldANDItalicRanges.append(range)
                    }

                    if bb && !ii {

                        boldRanges.append(range)
                    }

                    if ii && !bb {

                        italicRanges.append(range)
                    }
                }
            }

    cachedAttributedString!.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font_f], range: rangeAll)

    for r in boldANDItalicRanges {
        cachedAttributedString!.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font_fBOTH, range: r)
    }

    for r in boldRanges {
        cachedAttributedString!.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font_fb, range: r)
    }

    for r in italicRanges {
        cachedAttributedString!.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font_fi, range: r)
    }

    cachedAttributedString?.endEditing()
}
```

.

---

*Footnote. Just for clarity on a related point.  This sort of thing inevitably starts as a HTML string. Here's a note on how to convert a string that is html to an `NSattributedString` .... you will end up with nice attribute ranges (italic, bold etc) BUT the fonts will be fonts you don't want.*

```
fileprivate extension String {
    func htmlAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
        guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
            data: data,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
        return html
    }
}
```

.

*Even that part of the job is non-trivial, it takes some time to process. In practice you have to **background it** to avoid flicker.*

Comment: I just saw your footnote.. as I mentioned in the (newly written) notes in my answer, I'm also using the extension to override properties of text loaded from HTML. I'm also backgrounding and even caching it because it's so expensive. In case you need this, here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/manmal/c11ef79e306ffab25251ed911b3b0e80

Comment: Definitely a huge PITA!

Answer (score 1):

There is a tiny bug in the accepted answer causing the original font size to get lost.
To fix this simply replace

```
font.pointSize
```

with

```
f.pointSize
```

This ensures that e.g. H1 and H2 headings have the correct size.

Comment: nicely spotted.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

This properly scales the font size, as other answers overwrite the font size, which may differ, like with sub, sup attribute

For iOS replace `NSFont->UIFont` and `NSColor->UIColor`

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    
    func setFont(_ font: NSFont, textColor: NSColor? = nil) {
        
        guard let fontFamilyName = font.familyName else {
            return
        }
        
        beginEditing()
        enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, in: NSMakeRange(0, length), options: []) { (value, range, stop) in
            
            if let oldFont = value as? NSFont {
                let descriptor = oldFont
                    .fontDescriptor
                    .withFamily(fontFamilyName)
                    .withSymbolicTraits(oldFont.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits)
                // Default font is always Helvetica 12
                // See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring?language=objc
                let size = font.pointSize * (oldFont.pointSize / 12)
                let newFont = NSFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: size) ?? oldFont
                addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: newFont, range: range)
            }
        }
        if let textColor = textColor {
            addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:textColor], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length))
        }
        endEditing()
        
    }
    
}

extension NSAttributedString {
    
    func settingFont(_ font: NSFont, textColor: NSColor? = nil) -> NSAttributedString {
        let ms = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        ms.setFont(font, textColor: textColor)
        return ms
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Would it be valid to let a UITextField do the work?

Like this, given `attributedString` and `newfont`:

```
let textField = UITextField()
textField.attributedText = attributedString
textField.font = newFont
let resultAttributedString = textField.attributedText
```

---

Sorry, I was wrong, it keeps the "Character Attributes" like NSForegroundColorAttributeName, e.g. the colour, but not the UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits, which describe bold, italic, condensed, etc.

Those belong to the font and not the "Character Attributes". So if you change the font, you are changing the traits as well. Sorry, but my proposed solution does not work. The target font needs to have all traits available as the original font for this to work.

Comment: I tried it only with one color attribute and it did work, so hope the others work as well, had no time to fully test it.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, it keeps the "Character Attributes" like `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`, e.g. the colour, but not the `UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits`, which describe bold, italic, condensed, etc. which belong to the font and not the  "Character Attributes". So if you change the font, you are changing the traits as well. Sorry, but my proposed solution does not work. The target font needs to have all traits available as the original font for this to work.

Comment: Instead of adding an edit that states the answer is wrong, it would be better to delete the answer (or fix it if you can).