# iOS:Display long page content with many fonts and text styles

Tags: ios

What would be the best way to display long passage with rich text style(multiple font styles, color, image).

Attached screen is similar to the kind of content I need to display.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with UITextView? It gives you the full Text Kit engine; that's as fast, powerful, and full-featured as it gets on Mac or iOS.

Comment: How can we show the image, text with multiple fonts and styles? We could use attributedString for this but content size is too long(30 pages)

Comment: Honestly at this point in the app I would just **leave and go to a web page**.  ie, an internet URL.  Every single app these days, when you come to (for example) the legal terms and conditions.  It just cuts away to a normal URL in Safari.  There's no other real solution.

Comment: @Fattie, I do have other solution like use DTCoreText(https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) kind of thing but for this, I have to restructure content again into HTML and display it, it will not lag in performance as well. I fear to create HTML for all content, not sure if it is the best solution.

Comment: "We could use attributedString for this but content size is too long(30 pages)" I don't know why you say it's too long. You could lay it all out with PDF Kit if you want to paginate.

Comment: @matt PDF is another option but again need to create formatted PDF.

Answer (score 2):

The by far easiest approach is to convert your rich text to HTML and use a `UIWebView` to display it. The web view will take care of so many things:

- formatting
- scrolling
- loading fonts asynchronously
- loading images asynchronously

Comment: Good luck in finding an alternative that is sufficiently powerful and faster.

Comment: hi @SantoshSingh - this is the correct answer.  You "shouldn't be" displaying crap like this in an app.  if you have to do so - use a UIWebView!

Comment: Agreed, but as per my customer requirement, they have to display the long list of pages. There are many apps which use the long passage to display.

Comment: **Those apps use UIWebView.**   Also just tell your client "you simply go to a web page for that".  Note too that means the web page can be maintained over time.

Comment: @Fattie Agreed, but they have special requirements, I see few apps good in rich styling. For example, Mimo(https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mimo-learn-to-code-on-the-go/id1133960732?mt=8) how they are doing this.

Comment: they use UIWebView.

Comment: @Fattie Maybe UIWebView or they would have used NSAtttribuedString from HTML content for rendering. Isn't? NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)

Comment: actually @SantoshSingh you may want to review this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723345 very complicayed and annoying issue!  just FYI

Comment: @SantoshSingh: DTCoreText is a nice thing for this.