# How can I style HTML tags with Swift attributed string from HTML

Tags: html, css, swift, swiftui, nsattributedstring

I'm looking for ways to style the text attributes from a downloaded HTML string. I'm using the following code I found on this site to display the text in a view:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct HTMLView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var htmlString: String
    
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let data = Data(self.htmlString.utf8)
            if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
                uiView.isEditable = false
                uiView.attributedText = attributedString
            }
            
        }
    }
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UITextView {
        let label = UITextView()
        return label
    }
    
}
```

The code works great and the style tags are maintained but the font displayed is Times Roman and is very small.

[image: Default code]

I added this line of code, which represents the font family I want to use:

```
uiView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
```

The font changes but I lose all of the HTML styling.

[image: Modified font]

Is there a way to define h1, h2, h3, p, etc. with both font and weight?

Comment: You need to iterate over the font attribute, or you can simply "change" the HTML, by redefining yourself the size of the different CSS classes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723345/nsattributedstring-change-the-font-overall-but-keep-all-other-attributes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921972/parsing-html-into-nsattributedtext-how-to-set-font etc. There are plenty of related questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!!