# Using attributedText (NSAttributedString) on a UITextView on iOS6 only works with paragraph style or font but not both

Tags: ios, ios6, uitextview, nsattributedstring, css

I have been trying to use the attributedText property of UITextView to add adjustable line height to my custom UITextView. My code works fine in the simulator, but I am unable to make it work on an iPhone5. If I remove the font line the line height works but it the text reverts to a default smaller font. If I add the font, the font works but the paragraph styling is ignored. I have tried the code on a vanilla UITextView in a fresh app with the same behavior, which makes me think this is an iOS6 bug. Has anyone had any better luck?

I have also tried various UITextView replacements to add line height functionality, but nothing has worked out so far.

My code looks like this:

```
...
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight;
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = lineHeight;

NSString *text = self.text;
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:self.font range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];

self.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Thanks for any confirmation or suggestions anyone has!

Comment: Did you have any luck?  I am also struggling with an NSAttributedString/UITextView Issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169064/how-to-consistently-draw-nsattributedstring-in-uitextview-in-uitableviewcell

Comment: Any updates on this answer?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is indeed a bug. I've been struggling with it for the past few days and couldn't find any reasonable explanation.

Also, if you use IB to set up your UITextView, a few of those attributes won't be set as it should.

Anyway, I just filed a bug on that. http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2278401

Matt

Comment: Did you have any luck?  I am also struggling with an NSAttributedString/UITextView Issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169064/how-to-consistently-draw-nsattributedstring-in-uitextview-in-uitableviewcell