# Increase line space while editing UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I know after ios6, setAttributeString could help to change the line space,
but if I'm typing in the textview, may I change the line space, on ios7 setAttributeString seems work but not on iOS 6

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't change line space of textfield in iOS 6 because there is no API call available for iOS 6. Although you can use core text for this. Look this code for this https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: uitextview has a typingAttributes  after ios6 will it help?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in iOS 6, that causes line height to be ignored when font is set. See answer to [NSParagraphStyle line spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562506/nsparagraphstyle-line-spacing-ignored) ignored and longer bug analysis at [Radar: UITextView Ignores Minimum/Maximum Line Height in Attributed String.](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/12/radar-uitextview-ignores-minimummaximum-line-height-in-attributed-string/)